# What is wrong with this rudimentary code?

Tags: c

I have no idea why this code is wrong:

```
int sum = 0;

// take sum of every other digit starting with second-to-last and add to sum variable            
for (int i = length; i > 0; i -= 2)
{   
     sum += cardString[i];
     printf("%c | %i\n", cardString[i], sum);
}
```

Assuming the length is 15 and the "cardString" string is 378282246310005, here is the output of this program:

```
 | 0

0 | 48

0 | 96

3 | 147

4 | 199

2 | 249

2 | 299

7 | 354
```

I am honestly at a loss as to why this is happening.  Any ideas?

Comment: Try starting with `i = length - 1;`

Comment: What do you expect to happen?

Comment: "...at a loss as to why this is happening"? As to *what* is happening? Where do you see a problem?

Answer (score 5):

Problems:

- What you do is add ASCII codes of digits, not digits themselves.
- Fist digit you add is acutally null character which terminates the string

Changing

```
sum += cardString[i];
```

to

```
sum += cardString[i] - '0';
```

should fix first problem.

Second problem can be fixed by starting at correct place, which is two characters before terminating character:

```
for (int i = length - 2; i >= 0; i -= 2)
```

Look at this diagram for better understanding:

```
378282246310005X  <-- last character is null
^            ^ ^
|            | |
0            | length
             |
           length - 2
```

Comment: Thanks but it still isn't working.  Now all the values come out as negatives starting at -48.

Comment: @PaulR, what do you mean by that?  Regardless, the digit characters are consecutive in every character set I've ever seen.  Certainly in the popular ones.  Besides that, int this case they *do* appear to be ASCII, given the OP's output.

Comment: @PaulR nevertheless, C requires an encoding in which 0...9 are in order, so it doesn't make a difference. If you're nitpicky about wording, you could have upvoted my answer which you didn't...

Comment: @Jack - you also have to start at the right place, as mentioned by Blender in his comment to your question post.

Comment: But that would mess up my algorithm, which depends on the second to last digit being selected first.

Comment: change code in loop to `int i = length - 2; i >= 0`

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert the *characters* in the string to their numeric equivalent. Change:

```
            sum += cardString[i];
```

to:

```
            sum += cardString[i] - '0';
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sum += cardString[i];
```

doesn't do what you think it does - it doesn't add 0 for 0, 1 for 1 etc. - instead it adds its ASCII/Unicode/whichever encoding your system has character code of that character. Try

```
sum += cardString[i] - '0';
```

instead.

Answer (score 0):

You are summing up the character values of your string, not the numbers for which they stand.

Answer (score 0):

You are adding the ASCII-codes of the characters, not the digit values.

So there is an offset of 48 for each digit: '0' == 48

Answer (score 0):

cardString is a string and contains "378282246310005", that is in char {51,55,56,50,56,50,50,52,54,51,49,48,48,48,53,0}. The first element is the charater '3' which has 51 as value (ascii code). You add the ascii codes instead the value you expected.
To get the value of the digit simply subtract 48 (i.e. '0').
Take care to the bounds in your loop, it seems the first character you access is final nul character : remember array are 0 based in C.

```
cardString[0]='3' = 51
cardString[1]='7' = 55
and so on ...
cardString[14]='5' = 53
cardString[15]='\0' = 0
```

I guess you length is 15 ...

Answer (score 0):

The integer representation of a `char` need *not* be the base 10 representation of the character that you see in your string, and typically isn't. You're seeing ASCII integral values for characters, e.g. the ASCII value of `'0'` is *48*, hence your initial *48, 96*. See the ASCII chart for printable characters [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) for an explanation of your output.

You need to explicitly convert the character to an integer value. One trick is to subtract the integral value of `0` from a character that represents a number, to get an integer conversion, e.g. `'5' - '0'` yields `5`.

Your code has another problem: the loop is starting one index *past* the end of the string, at the null character. That's why your initial value is zero. Presumably you *don't* want to include that value in your sum, but if you do, as you see, it won't influence the sum, as the null character also has an integer value of zero. More correctly, your code would start at `length - 2`, since you say that you want to begin with the *second to last* character.